# How to get number of columns using google sheets api? Python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

How to get the number filled columns using google sheets api in python? or the notation like A7 of the first unfilled column ?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in an empty cell in google sheets:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE((A:A):(F:F))
```

and access it in python by using:

```
worksheet.cell(1, 1).value
```

when the first parameter is the row (that that command is in) and the second parameter is the column. If this is confusing or you have any questions, feel free to reply.